# Required field in another Panel is causing problems on ASP.NET Panel

Tags: asp.net, submit, panel

i have the following code

```
 <asp:Panel ID="searchPanel" DefaultButton="searchButton" runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="searchBox" runat="server" value="     Search..."></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Style="display: none" OnClick="searchInput" />
                </asp:Panel>



                                <asp:Panel ID="loginPanel" DefaultButton="submitButton" runat="server">

                                        <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server"  required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="password"  required="required"></asp:TextBox>

                                        <asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" Text="Log in" OnClick="login" />

                                </asp:Panel>
```

whenever i press 'enter' key when searchBox is focused, in the other panel fields are highlighted and says "Please fill the field".

How can I solve this?

Comment: You want to use validation groups I beleive

Comment: Or change the searchButton to not cause validation, e.g.
<asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Style="display: none" OnClick="searchInput" CausesValidation="false" />

Comment: @antmx that didnt work.

Comment: Where is the text "Please fill the field" coming from?

Comment: @brevik: I believe you are using HTML 5 attribute here. This attribute will cause validation if you are trying to post back the data.

Comment: i have solved the issue by using validation group. thanks @AndrewWalters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the issue by using validation group

```
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                    ControlToValidate="username"
                    ValidationGroup="emailValidationGroup"
                    runat="Server">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

 ValidationGroup="emailValidationGroup" //goes to button
```

also don't forget to add

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
```

to webconfig

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using HTML 5 "required" attribute. This will cause validation when you try to do a postback.

You can use a form specific for search control and use "novalidate" attribute in the form element.

Or

You can use validation groups to achieve this.

Comment: thanks ARS. i have solved the issue with using validation group.

Comment: one more thing, for some reason it doesn't check if the input is empty. how do i do that, do you know?